# If statements to check two conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

Trying to remove/filter away observations if two if one variable is NA but then not filter them if the variable Male is == 2

```
Ex <- readRDS("Session07//More data//ex.Rda")

Ex01 <- Ex %>%
  if(is.na(Ex$Idnumber02)=="TRUE"){
    if(Ex$Male==1){
      filter(!is.na(Idnumber02))
    }
  }
```

but it keeps returning this error:

```
Error in if (.) is.na(Exam$Idnumber02) == "TRUE" else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) is.na(Exam$Idnumber02) == "TRUE" else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does anyone(i am sure most of you do) know where im wrong ?

Comment: The pipe is doing absolutely nothing here. Sometimes I cringe thinking about what the tidyverse has done to R usage

Comment: No need to add equals TRUE here `if(is.na(xxxx)=="TRUE"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```
Ex = Ex %>% filter(!is.na(Idnumber02) | Male == '2')
```

Comment: Please change to `!is.na(Ex$Idnumber02)`

Comment: And why is `Ex$` added throughout? I thought that was why you people liked all of these pipes?

Comment: wrote it quickly, true on all counts!

Comment: Looking better. I would also remove the reference to a string `'2'`. OP gives no indication that it is not numeric

Comment: Also `Ex = Ex %>%` is not necessary. Instead `Ex %<>%`

Comment: Lastly, the logic may be incorrect. In your code "Male = 1 and "id2 is NA" will pass through. OP's description is not totally clear but may mean "filter if (id2 is missing AND Male is 1) OR Male is 2. That would be `Ex %>% filter( (!is.na(Idnumber02) & Male == 1) | Male == 2). OP should edit the question to be more clear.